# Ball collision time with ceiling

Tags: math, collision, gravity

I know to to do collision time with the ground.
Here's how I calculate that: gravityY = positive 9.81

```
float timeToGround = (velocity.y + Sqrt(velocity.y*velocity.y + 2f * gravityY * distanceToGround)) / gravityY;
```

How do I calculate the collision time to the roof/ceiling based on distance and initial velocity?

```
float timeToRoof = ?
```

I don't know where to look, thanks so much for your help

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO. I think your question needs a bit of clarification: is gravityY maintained as a vector? (i.e. if it is +9.81 when falling to the ground, will it be -9.81 when rising to the roof?) What is `velocity`? Is it the initial/final velocity?

Comment: gravity is constant, -9.81, just flipped - for simplicity. velocity is the current velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to solve quadratic equation for unknown time t

```
h = y0 + Vy * t  - g*t^2 / 2
or 
 g*t^2/2 - Vy*t + (h-y0) = 0  // a,b,c coefficient grouped
```

for known height of starting point y0, roof height h, gravity g, y-component of initial velocity Vy

Comment: wait, isn't this the exact same equation that i provided? am i missing something?

Comment: Yes, your formula represents solution of this equation for case `h=0, y0 = distanceToGround`. You can slightly correct it for you current task (that has not been properly formulated yet)

Comment: It's the same suvat formula, the same general principle; but you substitute in `g = -9.81` (negative acceleration, instead of positive) and `h - y0 = distanceToRoof`, so it's still different in some respects.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, thanks for your help.
Here's the answer:

```
float timeToRoof = (-velocity.y + Sqrt(velocity.y * velocity.y + 2f * gravity.y * distanceToRoof)) / gravity.y;
```

- gravity.y = negative -9.81
- velocity.y = current velocity
- distanceToRoof = current distance to roof